# Regex not validating November in a YYYY-MM-DD string

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm using this regex:

```
/^(((\d{4})(-)(0[13578]|10|12)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(-)(0[469]|1‌​1)(-)([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(-)(02)(-)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|(([02468]‌​[048]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([13579][26]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][0][48])(-)(0‌​2)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][2468][048])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][13579][26])(-)(02‌​)(-)(29)))$/
```

to validate dates, with their respective last day of the month, from an html input type date (format: YYYY-MM-DD), the point here is that it doesnt match for november (11th month). Why this is happening?

Comment: Use `0\d|1[0-2]` to match month

Comment: @hjpotter92 I need to validate last date of the month, first capturing group is for months with 31 days, second group is for 30 days

Comment: my bad, the regex string has hidden characters resulting on a failed match, added correct regex for future reference

Comment: Please don't answer your own questions in questions. Instead, use the `Add an Answer` button down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected regex:

```
/^(((\d{4})(-)(0[13578]|10|12)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(-)(0[469]|11)(-)([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(-)(02)(-)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|(([02468][048]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([13579][26]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][0][48])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][2468][048])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][13579][26])(-)(02)(-)(29)))$/
```